# Facebook, messages won't load, the page is blank

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm having trouble with messages on Facebook. When I try to open the page, it turns blank. I've tried to reload the page but it doesn't work.

I've also tried to log in as a different user and read messages, and that works. I tried it to make sure it wasn't a browser-related problem as I use IE8.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

A quick method is to press <kbd>shift</kbd> while clicking on refresh button in any of the browsers. This will completely reload the page overwriting all cached files.

Comment: Shift+Refresh is only applicable on certain browsers; each has its own way of handling things. See [Wikipedia's guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache) for a full list.

Comment: This is not a reload or cache issue.  I've run into it and once it started, I could not read my newsfeed or any other page on any of 4 browsers (including a new one I had never used before) and only got a white screen, but someone else in the house could read their newsfeed and other pages just fine.